# не создаются папки из java idea через mkdir()

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Создаю папки в среде с относительным путем:

```
String pathDest = "Projects/AllJava";
File dir=new File(pathDest);

dir.mkdirs();
```

все нормально. Но если использую полный путь:

```
String pathDest = "С:/Aux/All";
File dir=new File(pathDest);

dir.mkdirs();
```

папки нигде не создаются. Интересно, что если использую блок проверки

```
if(!dir.exists()){
  dir.mkdirs();
  System.out.println("Directory created.");
}
```

код входит в блок и выдается соответствующее сообщение в консоль, а папки не создаются?!
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: разве после диска не два `//`?

Comment: а права-то админские у текущего пользователя ?

Comment: Пути указывал разными способами: "C://Aux/All" и "C:\\Aux\All" - результата нет! И Да, я являюсь администратором - проверил...